# Problem with depth of field in specular reflection

Tags: cycles-render-engine, camera, depth-of-field, reflection

The reflection is not correct in the bottom. As you can see everything around it is blurred, except for the reflection of the railing. How do I fix this? I'm using 2.8 and cycles for rendering.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's absolutely correct. In real life and CG, the focal distance is a measure of the total ray length, reflected or not. Try it, next time you look at yourself in a mirror.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, this is coherent with reality. The reflected picture is practically at the same distance (or a bit more) of the real railing.

[image]

Comment: Thank you man, it looked so wrong but it makes sense now!